# Can't use protobuf in cmakelists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers

I am trying to run the example given in protobuf repo [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/examples), the c++ version. I have successfully installed the library and am able to run the `Makefile`. But on running the `CMakeLists.txt`, I get this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "protobuf" with any
  of the following names:

    protobufConfig.cmake
    protobuf-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "protobuf" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "protobuf_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "protobuf" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/cortana/Projects/CppProjects/proto/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/cortana/Projects/CppProjects/proto/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I have updated my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but this error is still there. How do I remove this error?

EDIT: 
CMakeLists.txt:

```
# Minimum CMake required
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

# Project
project(protobuf-examples)

include(FindProtobuf)
# Find required protobuf package
find_package(protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)

if(protobuf_VERBOSE)
  message(STATUS "Using Protocol Buffers ${Protobuf_VERSION}")
endif()

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR TRUE)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
    ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}
    ${THIRDPARTY_DIR}/protobuf-3.1.0
)

include_directories(${ProtobufIncludePath})

# http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_can_I_build_my_MSVC_application_with_a_static_runtime.3F
if(MSVC AND protobuf_MSVC_STATIC_RUNTIME)
  foreach(flag_var
      CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE
      CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO)
    if(${flag_var} MATCHES "/MD")
      string(REGEX REPLACE "/MD" "/MT" ${flag_var} "${${flag_var}}")
    endif(${flag_var} MATCHES "/MD")
  endforeach()
endif()

foreach(example add_person list_people)
  set(${example}_SRCS ${example}.cc)
  set(${example}_PROTOS addressbook.proto)

  #Code Generation
  if(protobuf_MODULE_COMPATIBLE) #Legacy Support
    protobuf_generate_cpp(${example}_PROTO_SRCS ${example}_PROTO_HDRS ${${example}_PROTOS})
    list(APPEND ${example}_SRCS ${${example}_PROTO_SRCS} ${${example}_PROTO_HDRS})
  else()

    foreach(proto_file ${${example}_PROTOS})
      get_filename_component(proto_file_abs ${proto_file} ABSOLUTE)
      get_filename_component(basename ${proto_file} NAME_WE)
      set(generated_files ${basename}.pb.cc ${basename}.pb.h)
      list(APPEND ${example}_SRCS ${generated_files})

      add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT ${generated_files}
        COMMAND protobuf::protoc
        ARGS --cpp_out ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} -I ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${proto_file_abs}
        COMMENT "Generating ${generated_files} from ${proto_file}"
        VERBATIM
      )
    endforeach()
  endif()

  #Executable setup
  set(executable_name ${example}_cpp)
  add_executable(${executable_name} ${${example}_SRCS} ${${example}_PROTOS})
  if(protobuf_MODULE_COMPATIBLE) #Legacy mode
    target_include_directories(${executable_name} PUBLIC ${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(${executable_name} ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES})
  else()
    target_link_libraries(${executable_name} protobuf::libprotobuf)
  endif()

endforeach()
```

EDIT 2: 
After trying for 2 hours, I couldn't fix the `CMakeLists.txt` provided by google examples. I wrote this basic one and it works for me:

```
PROJECT(protopuff)
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED (VERSION 3.5)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall -Werror -std=c++11")

INCLUDE(FindProtobuf)
FIND_PACKAGE(Protobuf REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR})
PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP(PROTO_SRC PROTO_HEADER addressbook.proto)
ADD_LIBRARY(proto ${PROTO_HEADER} ${PROTO_SRC})


INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
ADD_EXECUTABLE(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_add add_person.cc)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_list list_people.cc)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_add proto ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARY})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_list proto ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARY})
```

Comment: What version of `CMake` are you using ?

Comment: `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)`. I have `cmake 3.5.1` installed.

Comment: @JohnM. do you have multiple CMake versions installed (usually discouraged)? Make sure you're picking the right one

Comment: @MarcoA. No, I have just the one.

Comment: Have you tried what the error message says. I mean setting `protobuf_DIR` to the location you installed protobuf in ccmake or cmake-gui or via the command line.

Comment: Yes, I tried adding CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you show us your `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: @drescherjm I pointed my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to that location. Shouldn't that help? Sorry, but I dont know a lot about cmake.

Comment: Where are you setting `THIRDPARTY_DIR`? Also your setting of `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is too late. You must do that before the `find_package`

Comment: I haven't setup `THIRDPARTY_DIR`. What should it be pointing to? I have moved the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH code to below  `project(protobuf-examples)` line

Comment: ***What should it be pointing to?*** The folder containing `protobuf-3.1.0`

Comment: Is there a solution where I don't have to do that considering I am not distributing protobuf with my project and the folder containing protobuf might not be same for everyone? Also I did this : `set(${THIRDPARTY_DIR} /home/cortana/Libraries)` but am getting same error. `protobuf-3.1.0` is in `/home/cortana/Libraries/`

Comment: ***Is there a solution where I don't have to do that considering I am not distributing protobuf with my project and the folder containing protobuf might not be same for everyone?*** That is what find_package is supposed to do. The user is supposed to set `protobuf_DIR` in cmake-gui or ccmake when configuring with cmake to tell CMake where protobuf is installed when it is not in a standard location.

Comment: I didn't change the standard location though. Installation is done in `/usr/local/lib`

Comment: I would search your system for the `protobufConfig.cmake` or `protobuf-config.cmake` files. Are they in `/home/cortana/Libraries/protobuf-3.1.0` ?

Comment: There is a file `protobuf-config.cmake.in` in `/home/cortana/Libraries/protobuf-3.1.0/cmake/` but not the 2 files mentioned in error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132836/discussion-between-john-m-and-drescherjm).

Comment: GREAT! INCLUDE(FindProtobuf) just works

Comment: Is this problem resolved? I am observing the same error
using ndk toolchain for my compilation. I do not find ProtobufConfig.cmake or protobuf-config.cmake files either, but i have pkgconfig/protobuf.pc and pkgconfig/protobuf-lite.pc files

Answer (score 12):

Your problem is here:

```
find_package(protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

The name should start with uppercase: `Protobuf`. And that is the reason why your version is working; because in there, you have used correct case (last code snippet line 6):

```
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
```

[Here cmake documentation for find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html)

> The command searches for a file called `<name>Config.cmake` or `<lower-case-name>-config.cmake` for each name specified.

Comment: Why is the config not required?

Comment: I have just copied the line from where it is working in the question.(last code section 6th line). It is his decision not to use.

Comment: Got it. Yeah, it's interesting all the example documentation has Config Required, but no actual config files

Answer (score 0):

in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010398/how-to-link-google-protobuf-libraries-via-cmake-on-linux) thread fraser solved the problem but if you need to develop according to protobuf CMake config and find_package command in CMake for finding protobuf libraries. your protobuf library must be compiled with CMake and do not use configure routine .
after compile protobuf with CMake , a config file named protobuf-config.cmake will be generated into the prefix/lib/CMake/protobuf directory.

Answer (score 0):

The CmakeList.txt that is provided by the OP works on Linux but it does NOT work on Windows.

There is a way to make the actual CMakeList.txt work without any changes. The problem is that it requires the `CONFIG` parameter and that part is not documented anywhere. We need to provide the path to that config using `-Dprotobuf_DIR` parameter while generating the project.

On Windows, wherever you have installed protobuf, it will have `bin`, `cmake`, `include`, `lib` folders. We need to give the path of this `cmake` folder as an argument, like following:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 -B _build2 -Dprotobuf_DIR=C:/protobuf/install/cmake
```

This will build a solution file in the current directory.